# Change working location and print number of files in a shellscript

Tags: command-line, scripts, files

I want to retrieve the total number of files within a folder.

I would do this with `ls | wc -l`.
My code is:

```
cd /home/user/myfolder
num=$("ls | wc -l")
```

But I understand this opens a new shell which doesn't know that the working directory was changed. How can I execute the `ls | wc -l` command within the same shell?

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0):

Your command doesn't work merely because you quoted it, actually the action of [`bash` Command Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) *does* take place in the current working directory. However, as you should [avoid parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) I recommend a different approach.

I like using `find` for things like that:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf . | wc -c
```

This prints a `.` (`-printf .`) for every file (`-type f`) in the current directory (`.` and `-maxdepth 1`), `wc` then just counts the bytes in the output.